# потоки в NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, потоки-данных

Подскажите что я делаю неправильно, почему у меня появляется ошибка. Повторяю за учителем, у него всё работает. У меня выскакивает ошибка. Тема потоки самое начало.

```
var http = require('http').createServer().listen(8088);

http.on('request', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write('Start ...');

    setTimeout( function () {
        res.write('Finish.');
        //res.end(); - тут комментирую и получаю ошибку
    }, 3000);

    req.on('data', function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });

    req.on('end', function () {
        res.end();
    });
});




$ node stream.js
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write after end
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.write (_http_outgoing.js:426:15)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (F:\www\Dropbox\apps\git\js\courses\specialist\уровень
-5\модуль-3\stream.js:8:13)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:224:11)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:198:5)
```

Comment: Похоже, что  res.end()  вызывается раньше чем res.write('Finish.').
Попробуйте в req.on('end', function () {}) убрать строку res.end();

Comment: убрал. но страница в браузере бесконечно обновляется. всё таки нужет end(). А вот что я упустил никак не пойму.

Comment: @stasOk вам уже ответили, раскоментируйте строку res.end() в setTimeout( function () {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде как все просто. В соответствии с Вашим кодом запрос заканчивается, а когда таймаут срабатывает через три секунды, он еще что-то пытается записать куда-то. Выскакивает ошибка.

Окончание запроса должно звучать только в таймауте. И код должен иметь следующий вид:

```
var http = require('http').createServer().listen(8088);

http.on('request', function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.write('Start ...');

    setTimeout( function () {
        res.write('Finish.');
        res.end();
    }, 3000);

    req.on('data', function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
});
```